# How do I make this program reiterate its loop 10 times?

Tags: python, loops, repeat

How do I go about making this loop repeat and calculate a running total of 10 times then stop?  I know I have to use the range function, does it go above my int inputs? [picture of my code on replit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLT0a.jpg)

here's my code:

```
total = 0.0 
max = 10 

number_one = int(input("Enter a number:"))
first_sum = number_one
print("The total is", format(first_sum, ",.1f"), sep= " ")

number_two = int(input("Enter a number:")) 
second_sum = number_one + number_two
print("The total is", format(second_sum, ",.1f"), sep= " ")

number_three = int(input("Enter a number:"))
third_sum = number_one + number_two + number_three 
print("The total is", format(third_sum, ",.1f"), sep= " ")

number_four = int(input("Enter a number:"))
fourth_sum = number_one + number_two + number_three + number_four 
print("The total is", format(fourth_sum, ",.1f"), sep= " ")
```

Comment: Would be better if you can type your codes to your question, so others do not re-type the whole code.

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/its-vs-its/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
iter = 1
max = 10

numbers = []

while iter <= 10:
    user_input = int(input(f'Enter number {iter} => '))
    numbers.append(user_input)
    iter += 1

result = sum(numbers)
print(f'\nThe total is {result}.')
```

Result:

```
Enter number 1 => 20
Enter number 2 => 30
Enter number 3 => 40
Enter number 4 => 50
Enter number 5 => 12
Enter number 6 => 16
Enter number 7 => 13
Enter number 8 => 16
Enter number 9 => 17
Enter number 10 => 15
The total is 229.
```

**Edit**

Or, alternatively using `for` loop:

```
numbers = []
for iter in range(1, 11):
    user_input = int(input(f'Enter number {iter} => '))
    numbers.append(user_input)

result = sum(numbers)
print(f'\nThe total is {result}.')
```